# Did East Asian responses to the Spanish Civil War divide along 'party lines'?

Tags: china, japan, spanish-civil-war

Did Chiang Kai-Shek and Hirohito, and other leaders of China and Japan, see any parallels between the Sino-Japanese war and the Spanish Civil War? Did Chiang make any message of support for the Spanish Republic, or did he not just see it as relevant to him and his problems?

NOTE: I realise that this question is 'broad', but as I was unable to find anything it seemed futile to write the question in a way that would limit its scope to one country or group of people, because information on the subject is likely to be scarce. I will be interested in an answer that tells me about the responses of even a small number of people in China or Japan, or for that matter Vietnam, Burma, Korea, Siam...

Answer (score 4):

Both Japan and China had more pressing issues than a civil war half the world away.
Note that long distance travel was harder and more expensive then.

## China

[wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_Civil_War#cite_ref-123):

> Some Chinese joined the Brigades, and the majority of them eventually returned to China, while some went to prison or French refugee camps, and a handful remained in Spain

Benton, Gregor; Pieke, Frank N. (1998). [The Chinese in Europe](http://books.google.com/books?id=_aqcIT11ShsC) p. 215

## Japan

After being spurned [in Paris](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treaty_of_Versailles), Japan took little notice of European development.

Comment: I realise it was a long way away, but then again, people in Europe believed that what happened between China was relevant to them, so...

Thank you, I didn't notice that buried in the citation on the page. If anyone can provide more detail I'll be very interested.